# Using Javascript or HTML To POST Secure SSL Login

Tags: php, javascript, post, ssl, authentication

Just wondering which is more secure for POST'ing data for a secure login. I am using SSL to protect the data in transit, and phpass to manage hashing and salting the passwords server side.

Basically,

Either,

```
<form action="user-man.php" method="POST">
Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="user" size="60"><br>
Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="pass" size="60"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Create user">
</form>
```

**Or**

```
// DEFINE FUNCTION TO REQUEST TO PORTAL PHP FILE HANDLING REQUESTS
function phpRequest( command, username, password )
{
    if( command == "tryLogin" )
    {   
        $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: 'open.php',
        data: { request: command, user: username, pass: password },
        success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR )
        {           
            alert(data);
        }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security is the same.  It makes no difference whether or not you use JavaScript or an HTML form, the same type of request goes to the server.

Use HTTPS for everything.

Comment: Thanks for that. Just clarifying my paranoia - accepting answer the second I can :)

Comment: @tsujp, I recommend firing up a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to see what gets sent over the wire.  It's good to know what goes on behind the curtain.

Comment: Downloading that now. Once I add all the functionality for my login system I will be sure to have a crack.